# Some Android phones not opening “About device” page in Settings?

Tags: java, android

Some Android phones don't do anything when the the code below is ran. It's supposed to open the "About device" page in Settings.

For example, I know for a fact that it has no effect on the Huawei Y9 Prime 2019 **running Android 10**.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS));
```

What's the best way to safeguard against this issue when it occurs? (In my app, I open this page to ask the user to perform a specific action there)

Comment: Have you tried `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: @MohammadOmidvar How should I use it elegantly in my case?

Comment: I haven't faced the same issue before, but as there are many devices with incompatibilities (especially among Huawei ones), you can always check for this kind of stuff to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: From the docs: `In some cases, a matching Activity may not exist, so ensure you safeguard against this.` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS

Comment: @MDP I'm aware of this. What I'm asking for is the best way to safeguard against this issue when it happens.

Comment: The remedy would be checking for the device manufacturer and using that manufacturer's custom APIs. For example: `com.huawei.hms.location.SettingsClient` for accessing location on Huawei devices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `PackageManager.resolveActivity()` to check whether such an `Activity` exists. If that returns `null`, there is no activity that matches the `Intent` and you have to guide your customers to the settings in another way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS);
ResolveInfo resolveInfo = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0);
if (resolveInfo == null) {
    // help customers by describing how to get to the device info settings

} else {
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: How can I test this code to make sure it works? I don't have a Huawei phone unfortunately.

Comment: That's the difficult part as there are so many Android devices and manufacturers. Google did think about this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab

Comment: OK. I just tested this out and the 'About device' page opens normally on the available Huawei devices. They don't have the Huawei Y9 Prime 2019 :( So I wasn't able to verify if your code works.

Comment: Maybe Huawei can provide some test phones: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59316655/4706541

Comment: They need ID verification to create a Huawei developer account. Due to privacy concerns, I can't provide them with it.

Comment: How can I emulate an activity that doesn't exist to test your code? Do you have an example of an activity that doesn't exist?

Comment: You can't, you need Huawei's OS in order to test it, but Huawei does not provide any images to setup an emulator. Using their cloud debugging service is your best option or you need to find a friend with a Huawei Y9 Prime 2019.

Comment: That's not what I meant. What I meant is: are there any activities that are known not to exist on Samsung devices for example? That way, I can test your code on my Samsung device.

Comment: That's easy, you can make up an action like `Intent("com.company.app.ACTION_THAT_DOES_NOT_EXIST")` that's guaranteed not to find a matching `Activity`

Comment: I tried `new Intent(Settings.ACTION_INEXISTENT_ACTIVITY);` but Android Studio doesn't let me build. Can you tell me step by step what I need to do?

Comment: Because that field does not exist in `Settings`, that's why I put in a `String` of my own (of a non-existent action). Read through the official docs to better understand Intents and Intent Filters: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters

Answer (score 0):

If an activity is not found, the method `startActivity` will throw `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException`. You should catch this exception and notify the user:

```java
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_DEVICE_INFO_SETTINGS));
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    // Notify the user, eg. using a popup so they can open settings manually 
}
```

Comment: I don't think the user is experiencing a crash, so that's not the solution