# How to create an emulator implemented with emui

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I have an application that depends on google services, i did too much migration in order to let the new Huawei phones run my application.

Unfortunately i couldn't test my application on emulator due to HMS core is missing, i have created a new Stock android image and i tried to install HMS core APK but the app could not be installed as the image [image: here],

Unfortunately [cloud debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug) not serving me due to the huge services. and i need to see everything step by step. any solution expect that i buy a new phone without google services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try HMS plugin
Go to File-> Setting-> Plugins and search for HMS Toolkit and install it.
Visit the article [HMS Toolkit - Automatic HMS SDK Integration](https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201249144855100206&fid=0101188387844930001) To know detail about HMS installation and usage.

Once you select debugging and choose devices you can select EMUI version from there.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using kits that do not depend on Huawei phones, such as Push Kit, ML Kit, Scan Kit, and In-App Purchases, you can download [HUAWEI AppGallery](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/mobileservices/appgallery/?fromConsumer=en_homepage_AppGallery&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIu7GIhYau7AIVRaaWCh2Ohga-EAAYASAAEgKVrvD_BwE) on a non-Huawei phone and then run your app. In this case, you will be automatically guided to download and install HMS Core (APK) on AppGallery. You can also use the **adb** command to manually install HMS Core (APK) and then run your app for testing. For details, please refer to [EMUI Version-Dependent Features](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/emui-version-dependent-0000001050042515).

If you are using kits that depend on Huawei phones, such as FIDO, Map Kit, and Health Kit, you can use [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-introduction) to debug apps. (Cloud Debugging cannot debug code step by step.)

Work with Cloud Debugging at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877454/14006527.

Answer (score 1):

we can use android emulator before that you need to download latest HMS Core APK install into your emulator, all HMS kits doesn't supports. better you can go with cloud debugging or Install Hms plugin in your android studio use cloud debugging.