# Support Android App with One Signal Cordova Plugin SDK in Huawei App Gallery

Tags: android, cordova, onesignal, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I'm currently using **onesignal-cordova-plugin v2.10.1** in my ionic android app for push notifications. Now we are planning to support the android app in Huawei App Gallery using the same One Signal push notifications. What I need to do specifically with this requirement?

1. In One Signal settings, configure Huawei Android (HMS) Configuration.
   [image]

2. Can I still use **one-signal-cordova-plugin** or I have to use new plugin **cordova-plugin-hms-push**?

Answer (score 0):

1. About Huawei Android(HMS) Configuration
   Before you start developing an app, you must register as a Huawei developer and complete identity verification on HUAWEI Developers. Create an app in AppGallery Connect, and get the information about APP ID and APP SECRET.

The basic process is as follows:

1). Log in to [the HUAWEI Developer official website](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en) and rgister as a developer.

2). Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and click **My apps**.

3). Click **New app** on the right of the page.

4). Fill in the app information and click **OK**. The app information page is displayed.

2. You need to use HMS Cordova Push Plugin. Your app integrated with the Push SDK to obtain a push token, and sent the token to OneSignal SDK. OneSignal uses the token to send the messages to devices and the devices receive the messages.

Comment: How can I test whether the push notifications and other features are working fine in Huawei phone without google play services if I don't have any physical Huawei device?

Comment: @Lily.T You can use [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug) to debug an app on a real device. Please kindly refer to this answer [Android Virtual Device for Huawei Mobile Services](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877454/13329100)

Comment: can I know is there any restriction for devices in cloud debugging to receive push notifications from one signal?

Comment: It is recommended that you use an Android 10 or later phone. And do not use an emulator.