# Huawei Ads: check hms sdk available error

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-ads

I'm trying to implement huawei ads in my app.

I'm testing on samsung galaxy s7 with HMS Core 5.0.2.301 installed.

I've tried running sample from https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-ads-demo-java

But I keep getting **onRewardAdFailedToLoad error 3** which indicates no ads

Also in logcat I see this line: `check hms sdk available error`

What should I do to resolve it?

LogCat:

```
I/HiAdSDK.LocationUtils:  loc_tag sendAsyncLocationByNative failed because switch is off
I/HiAdSDK.LocationUtils:  loc_tag isLocationAvailable = false, return null
I/HiAdSDK.Decouple.PPSApiServiceManager:  call remote method: reqRewardAd
V/Surface: sf_framedrop debug : 0x4f4c, game : false, logging : 0
I/HiAdSDK.Decouple.PPSApiServiceManager:  call reqRewardAd code: 200 msg: null
I/HiAdSDK.RewardAdLoader:  onAdFailed, errorCode:204
```

Comment: Hi. You are testing on samsung galaxy s7. Plz use Huawei phones. If you do not have  huawei devices, plz try [Cloud Debuging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug).

Comment: Thanks @shirley, it works on cloud emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Code 3 means the ad request is successful, but the server does not return any available ad asset. Currently, Huawei Ad Kit supports Huawei devices, please use Huawei phones to test your app.

If you do not have an Huawei phone, you can use [Cloud Debugging of AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-realtimedebug) to test it. Cloud Debugging tests your app using mainstream Huawei devices provided by Huawei. You can run your app on the latest and most popular Huawei devices to test app functions.

Please kindly refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877454/13329100

For more details, see:
[Error Codes](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/error-code-0000001051073340)
[Supported Devices](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/publisher-service-introduction-0000001070671805#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001070671805__section1555784412114)