# honor 50 cannot be detected as device in android studio

Tags: android, huawei-developers

Honor 50 is the first Honor phone that is separated from Huawei and is not supported by Hi Suite. Hence, android studio can't detect it as a development device.

how to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

The chipset is Qualcomm SM7325 / Snapdragon 778G 5G, therefore I'd assume ...
that the device should become known after installing the "Qualcomm USB driver".

Answer (score 0):

What operating system is your Honor 50? Can you see the device using the `adb devices` command?

You could also try to use [Cloud Debugging](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-clouddebug-introduction) of AppGallery Connect to see whether it could solve the problem of device identification failure.

Furthermore, [this answer might help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63877454/13329100).

Answer (score 0):

eventually installing latest version of honor app solves the issue

Comment: What is honor app?