# Where can I test my app on real devices such as Huawei,Xiaomi, Redmi?

Tags: android-studio, huawei-mobile-services, xiaomi

I have developed an application and would like to test how it works on real devices such as Huawei,Xiaomi, Redmi???
How can i do that? Please recommend free sites or ways to do that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64002349/13329100

Comment: maybe there are other ways, since I would not like to indicate my passport data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Enable your xiomi developer option, by typing MIUI Version until "you are now developer" message pop up.

Goto aditional setting -> developer option, and enable "usb debugging". You need to enable "install via usb".

When you connect your phone using cable data, you need to grant access your phone from PC (Android Studio).

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm looking for virtual ways. I don't physically have Huawei,Xiaomi, Redmi. )